# What to do when audio is not getting properly captured?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-recording

I have a mixer (Behringer XENYX 1024USB) that I connected to my pc. The device shows up in my audio device list but fails to capture any audio.

Even after a lot of googling and even reading the chip's datasheet (the usb interface chip is a Texas Instruments PCM2902), I failed to fix the issue. Things I tried is changing/patching the driver and trying to get it to work in Jack, without results.

What are some things I can try? I am using `pulseaudio` and `alsa` (which comes by default?)

I have a dump of `pacmd list-sources` [here](https://hastebin.com/awexubifab.apache)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, using a USB 2.0 port and a USB 3.0 port makes a difference.